# Object on Image does not move when Image moves

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, zooming

I have two classes. The first, `JPanelImage`, adds an `Image` to my `JPanel`. The second, `myObjet`, represents the object I want to add on my `Image`. The `Image` can move and can zoom.

The problem is that when I move the image, the object remains fixed.

Class `JImagePanel`:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

class JImagePanel extends Panel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5375994938523354306L;
    private  MediaTracker tracker;
    private Image img;
    private Dimension imgSize,iniSize;
    private int zoom = 0 ;
    private int MouseX;
    private int MouseY;
    int transX=0;
    int transY=0;

    public JImagePanel(String file){
        //setSize(100,200);
        img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
    setLayout(null);
        tracker=new MediaTracker(this);

        tracker.addImage(img,0);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                MouseX = e.getX();
                MouseY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                transX += e.getX()-MouseX;
                transY += e.getY()-MouseY;
                MouseX = e.getX();
                MouseY = e.getY();

                repaint();
            }
        });

        try{
            tracker.waitForAll();
        }
        catch(Exception ie){}
        imgSize=iniSize=new Dimension(img.getWidth(this),img.getHeight(this));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(imgSize);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        if(imgSize.width<=iniSize.width) {
            imgSize=iniSize; 
        }

        g.drawImage(this.img, (getWidth()-imgSize.width)/2+transX, (getHeight()-imgSize.height)/2+transY, imgSize.width,imgSize.height,this);
    }
    public void zoomIn(){
        int x=10*imgSize.width/100; 
        int y=10*imgSize.height/100;
        imgSize=new Dimension(imgSize.width+x,imgSize.height+y); 
        if(imgSize.width>iniSize.width){
            setSize(imgSize);
            getParent().doLayout();
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void zoomOut(){
        int x=10*imgSize.width/100;
        int y=10*imgSize.height/100;
        imgSize=new Dimension(imgSize.width-x,imgSize.height-y);
        if(getWidth()>iniSize.width)
        {
            setSize(imgSize);
            getParent().doLayout();

        }
        repaint();
    }

    public int getZoom() {
        return zoom;
    }
```

Class `myObjet`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class myObjet extends JPanel {

    JLabel lblName,lblAct,lblSeuil ;
    JPanel panelObjet;

    public myObjet(String NameObjet ,double activite  )
    {
        ImageIcon img = createImageIcon("images/Source.png");
        lblName = new JLabel(img);
        lblAct = new JLabel(String.valueOf(activite));
        panelObjet = new JPanel();
        panelObjet.setToolTipText(NameObjet);
        panelObjet.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelObjet.add("North",lblName);
        panelObjet.add("South",lblAct);
       add(panelObjet);
       isOpaque();
    }

    public ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cette image n'existe pas : " + path, "Erreur", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            //  System.err.println("L'image n'est pas dans : " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public boolean isOpaque()
    {
        return true ; 
    }
}
```

---

MYObject is alone , i adds this Object in Panel of this Image .

Here is a concrete example of how I use these classes

```
public static void (String [] args )
   {
imagePanel = new JImagePanel("/home/Image.png");
p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     //   p.setBounds(0,0,0,0);
        p.add(getImagePanel());
        ple2.add("Center",p);

}
```

2/ in actionPerformed :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {



    Object sourceEv = ev.getSource() ; 




    if(sourceEv == action.jpfI.btnFrame[4])
    {   
        df =  new DecimalFormat("0.00");


        int x = Integer.valueOf(action.jpfI.lblTxt[4].getText());
        int y =Integer.valueOf(action.jpfI.lblTxt[5].getText()) ;
        x =(int)(x/0.26) ;
        y =(int)(y/0.26):


        objet = new myObjet("islem","0.002");
        objet.setBounds(x,y , 50,50);


        action.getImagePanel().addImage(objet);
        action.repaint();

    }
```

Comment: I can think of a number of issues, but I need more information.  How is the "myObject" pane been associated with the image pane?  Is it been added to the image pane or are they been added to a common container?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've come across three issues.

Firstly: There's no layout manager on the image pane.  No big deal, but if you're not going to use a layout manager, you become responsible for laying out any child components.  I fixed this (and it's in the wrong place) by adding the following to the "myObjet" class.

```
Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
setBounds(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
```

This really should be taken care of by the JImagePanel - either add a layout manager or check the doLayout method.

Secondly: The JImagePanel is a heavy weight component.  You should avoid mixing heavy and light weight components if you can (there are Z order issues amongst other things).  I updated the JImagePanel to extend from a JPanel.

Thridly: You should only very rarely have to override the paint method.  In your case I can understand why you did, but what you ended up doing was painting on the top of everything else (and mixed with the fact you were using a heavy weight component compounded the issue).

I changed the "paint" for "paintComponent" which paints the background and was able to get it to work nicely.  I was able to move the image around and have the "myObjet" visible and static in place.

**UPDATE**

Okay...

```
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            transX += e.getX() - MouseX;
            transY += e.getY() - MouseY;
            MouseX = e.getX();
            MouseY = e.getY();

            // Add this to your code
            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {

                comp.setLocation(transX, transY);

            }

            repaint();
        }
```

In fact, a better solution would be to allow the parent container to handle the movement and set the image and objects statically with in the image pane (my pane was set to a static size).  The basic idea you have running here just needs to be moved to the container.

The only other thing you would need to deal with is the Z order of the panes.

Comment: Thank you , but can you post the new CODE ? .

Comment: I would like move the all object with to Image.

Comment: I have try this code but my object remains fixed if I move the Image . 
I adds this code in JImagePanel , but could you post the all update code . Thank you .